# I don't have cron jobs on my server. What is an alternative for sending emails without user input?

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks

I am looking for a way to have some way to have a script execute itself without my input. Is this possible? And it not, what would be another option? I don't care to use a 3rd party site for cron jobs either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could build the code into a web-visible PHP script, and then register it with a URL monitoring service like http://mon.itor.us/ that will load your URL every half hour.

(I'm not sure what you mean by "3rd party site for cron jobs" - hopefully this isn't it. :-)

Comment: I agree this sounds brilliant +1. I just want to make sure I understand though, I set up the url to a file and it will automatically run that file by loading it? Therefore executing the PHP? It sounds too good to be true!

Comment: Yes, just by writing a PHP script under your site as you normally would.  So your script is at `http://mysite.com/do-my-scheduled-stuff.php`, then register that URL with a monitoring service.  (The point of the monitoring service is not just to regularly load the URL, but to monitor it to ensure it's working, and then email you if it isn't - which of course is also very useful to you!)

Comment: Excellent, I have tried it out and it seems to work well except it only appears it ran twice within like the same minute. I assume you are familiar with the site, how can I change how many times it loads? (E.g. every two minutes?)

Comment: I believe the free service from mon.itor.us runs every 30 minutes.  I don't about the paid one.  There are any number of such services on the net, most of which have a free option: http://www.google.com/search?q=website+monitoring

Answer (score 1):

http://cronless.com

https://www.setcronjob.com

https://www.easycron.com

Use above third party cron jobs providers. :)