# Is there a way to make my website automatically scan database and do pre determined functions?

Tags: php, mysql

Let me do some explaining, I am developing a website that has expiry dates and what I want it to do is to send an email to the user when the timer expires.

However going by my logic it only sends the email to the user just as he goes online on the website which might be days after the expiry date has been reached.

So here's my question, is there a way to make the website do an automatic scan of the database and then send email to those who have an expired order?

Comment: you need to create a cronjob on your server and call your php file that executes this task

Comment: I'll have to do more research on that thank you for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [notify by email on expiry date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399715/notify-by-email-on-expiry-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out I had to do a cron job